# How to login to website when username and password are the same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to login into a site and when I right-click and inspect the elements of both the username textbox and the password textbox, both appear to have the same naming conventions.  Normally, these have distinct names, but in the site I am looking at (behind a firewall so I can't share it), it seems like the class names are exactly the same.

```
Username:
<input class="card-form-text__kquJs" tabindex="0">

Password:
<input class="card-form-text__kquJs" tabindex="0" type="password">

Button:
<div class="cover-content-red__17vUN" style="transform: translate(100%, 0%) matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);">LOGIN</div>
```

I tried the code below and it didn't work.

```
import requests
url = 'https://corporate_site.com/network'
values = {'card-form-text__kquJs': 'my_email',
          'card-form-text__kquJs': 'my_password'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with Selenium... Why did you add this tag? You can try `r = requests.post(url, auth=('my_email', 'my_password'))`

Comment: The input's class is not the name. You might have some js doing stupid tricks with the form submission...

Comment: After I pass in the username and password I need to click a button.  That's why.

Comment: I removed the [selenium] tag since there's no reference to Selenium here. You should probably add some more tags based on the libraries you are using in your code sample.

Comment: Those two `INPUT`s are not the same, they just happen to have the same class applied. I'm not sure if you are looking for a locator or what. The password `INPUT` has `type="password"` so you can use that to differentiate the two, if needed.

Comment: If they come in a predictable order, populate them in that order.